# how do i iterate over keys in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

[EDITED for Clarity and Corrections]
apologies for the early rushed post. I have **scraped** and obtained a json formatted response. The json code is as below:

```
{
"item":{
  "itemid":7041360985,
  :
  :
  : 
  "models":[
     {
        "itemid":7041360985,
        "status":1,
        "current_promotion_reserved_stock":0,
        "name":"",
        "promotionid":0,
        "price":2524141,
        "price_stocks":[
           {
              "model_id":65873300871,
              "stockout_time":0,
              "region":"MY",
              "rebate":"None",
              "price":4301287,
              "promotion_type":0,
              "allocated_stock":"None",
              "shop_id":449183886,
              "end_time":"None",
              "stock_breakdown_by_location":[
                 
              ],
              "item_id":11825286664,
              "promotion_id":0,
              "purchase_limit":"None",
              "start_time":"None",
              "stock":3
           }
        ],
        "current_promotion_has_reserve_stock":false,
        :
     }
  ],
  "min_purchase_limit":0,
  :
  }
```

I am trying to get the name and price details from each models if available. Sometimes, there would be no model at all, sometimes there would be 4.

Below is my attempt to access the dictionary values, but I am getting this:

type1 = model['name']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

```
    def parse_data(self, response):
    resp = json.loads(response.body)

    for model in resp.get('models'):
        type1 = model['name']
            # 'type1price': model['price'],
        yield{
            'product': resp.get('item').get('name'),
            'upcoming_flash_sale': resp.get('item').get('name'),
            'rating': resp.get('item').get('item_rating').get('rating_star'),
            'review numbers': resp.get('item').get('cmt_count'),
            'viewcount': resp.get('item').get('view_count'),
            'likes': resp.get('item').get('liked_count'),
            'type1': type1,
            'location': resp.get('item').get('shop_location')
        }
```

Product details, such as likes, review numbers, etc are obtained from outside the key 'models'. In the end, I would like to merge them with the data obtained from within 'models'.

How do I loop through all available items, if there more than one dictionary of item models (while not breaking the code, if there's none)?

Comment: There looks to be a top-level key `'item'` that your code is not handling. Try `resp['item']['models']`?

Comment: For given code how will you get `'type1': resp.get('models')[0]['name'], TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.`? You never used `resp.get('models')[0]['name']` expression in your code. What you use is `model[0]['name']`. Share output traceback of given code so we can see which line is error

Comment: Also model variable is dictionary and not list, so model[0] will give key error

Comment: Just remove the `[0]`. `model` is a dict, not a list. That said, the `yield` looks pretty odd. You might want to show your exact expected output so others can help guide you to it.

Comment: That will not solve problem as model is Nonetype i think. OP should share traceback for original code

Comment: Good point, I'm just going to vote "needs details or clarity" (or [mcve])...

Comment: apologies! I was trying many ways and it was a rushed posts. I have messed up the codes and outputs.. I have edited my post to better reflect my issue. Thank you!

Comment: *Product details, such as likes, review numbers, etc are obtained from outside the key 'models'. In the end, I would like to merge them with the data obtained from within 'models'.* - I don't see any such fields in your input. Also that is not in correct JSON format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding of your input and description, I think you want to print the names and prices of all models (There can be None).

This code will print the `name` and `price` of all models (if they exist).

```
import json
s = '''
{
   "item":{
      "itemid":7041360985,
      "models":[
         {
            "itemid":7041360985,
            "status":1,
            "current_promotion_reserved_stock":0,
            "name":"",
            "promotionid":0,
            "price":2524141,
            "price_stocks":[
               {
                  "model_id":65873300871,
                  "stockout_time":0,
                  "region":"MY",
                  "rebate":"None",
                  "price":4301287,
                  "promotion_type":0,
                  "allocated_stock":"None",
                  "shop_id":449183886,
                  "end_time":"None",
                  "stock_breakdown_by_location":[
                     
                  ],
                  "item_id":11825286664,
                  "promotion_id":0,
                  "purchase_limit":"None",
                  "start_time":"None",
                  "stock":3
               }
            ],
            "current_promotion_has_reserve_stock":false
         }
      ],
      "min_purchase_limit":0
   }
}
'''
j = json.loads(s)
if j['item'].get('models'):
    for i in j['item']['models']:
        name = i['name']
        price = i['price']
        print(f'Name: {name}\tPrice: {price}')
```

```
Name:   Price: 2524141
```

Comment: thank you! That worked! but how do i do a yield instead of print? because i want to save it as csv along other data collected from that particular product.

Answer (score 1):

To get a keys of a dictionary as a list, you can do:

```
dictionary.keys()
```

This will give you a list of keys in the dictionary and then you can iterate over them.

If you do not want the list of the keys and just want to iterate over them:

```
for i in dictionary:
    print(i) # Prints the dictionary keys
    print(dictionary[i]) # Prints the dictionary values
```

Comment: apologies! I was trying many ways and it was a rushed posts. I have messed up the codes and outputs.. I have edited my post to better reflect my issue. Thank you!